# JDateChooser e JComboBox pegando valores em branco

Tags: java, swing

Estou com alguns problemas ao tentar capturar o valor de alguns elementos do meu código.

**1º - Problema com componente JDateChoose**

O código roda sem problemas porém o valor capturado fica em branco, segue código

```
 String dtreceb = ((JTextField) this.txtdtreceb.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
```

**2º - Problema com o componente JComboBox**

Ao tentar capturar o valor, o código escreve "NULL" no banco de dados

```
 String trincado = (String) txttrincado.getSelectedItem();
```

Código completo da aplicação;

```
package matheus.arruda.lab.wn.tratermik;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;

import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.RowSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormSpecs;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.Choice;
import java.awt.List;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.Box;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import com.ibm.icu.text.DateFormat;
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import com.toedter.components.JSpinField;
import com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar;
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class novaos extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtos;
    JComboBox txtcliente = new JComboBox<Object>();
    JComboBox txttrincado = new JComboBox();
    JComboBox txtamassado = new JComboBox();
    JComboBox txtpesodiv = new JComboBox();
    private JTextField txtresp;
    private JTextField txtqtdpesodiv;
    JLabel lblQtdPesoFora = new JLabel();
    JDateChooser txtdtreceb = new  JDateChooser();
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField txtcopiacliente;
    private JTextField txtoutrasdiv;
    private JTextField txtoutrasdiv1;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    novaos frame = new novaos();
                    frame.setVisible(true);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });




    }


private void fechar() {
    this.dispose();
}

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public novaos() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(novaos.class.getResource("/com/jgoodies/looks/plastic/icons/File.gif")));

        setTitle("Tratermik Metais  - Nova O.S");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(136, 55, 694, 661);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);




        JLabel lblos = new JLabel("#O.S:");
        lblos.setBounds(10, 48, 46, 20);
        lblos.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        contentPane.add(lblos);

        txtos = new JTextField();
        txtos.setEditable(false);
        txtos.setBounds(59, 48, 46, 20);
        txtos.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        contentPane.add(txtos);
        txtos.setColumns(2);
        buscar_dados();

        JLabel lblCliente = new JLabel("Cliente:");
        lblCliente.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblCliente.setBounds(157, 48, 66, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblCliente);

        JLabel lblRespRelatrio = new JLabel("Respons\u00E1vel:");
        lblRespRelatrio.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblRespRelatrio.setBounds(10, 79, 117, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblRespRelatrio);

        txtresp = new JTextField();
        txtresp.setBounds(128, 81, 211, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtresp);
        txtresp.setColumns(10);

        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        separator.setBounds(0, 128, 243, 8);
        contentPane.add(separator);

        JLabel lblCaracteristicasDoMatrial = new JLabel("Caracteristicas do Mat\u00E9rial");
        lblCaracteristicasDoMatrial.setBounds(253, 122, 165, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblCaracteristicasDoMatrial);

        JSeparator separator_1 = new JSeparator();
        separator_1.setBounds(421, 128, 267, 8);
        contentPane.add(separator_1);

        JLabel lblMaterialTrincado = new JLabel("Material Trincado?");
        lblMaterialTrincado.setBounds(21, 140, 106, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblMaterialTrincado);

        JComboBox txttrincado = new JComboBox();
        txttrincado.setBounds(10, 163, 129, 25);
        contentPane.add(txttrincado);
        txttrincado.addItem("");
        txttrincado.addItem("Sim");
        txttrincado.addItem("Não");

        JComboBox txtamassado = new JComboBox();
        txtamassado.setBounds(169, 163, 129, 25);
        contentPane.add(txtamassado);
        txtamassado.addItem("");
        txtamassado.addItem("Sim");
        txtamassado.addItem("Não");
        JLabel lblMaterialAmassado = new JLabel("Material Amassado?");
        lblMaterialAmassado.setBounds(169, 140, 118, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblMaterialAmassado);




        JComboBox txtpesodiv = new JComboBox();
        txtpesodiv.setBounds(331, 163, 129, 25);
        contentPane.add(txtpesodiv);
        txtpesodiv.addItem("");
        txtpesodiv.addItem("Sim");
        txtpesodiv.addItem("Não");
         txtpesodiv.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    //
                    // Get the source of the component, which is our combo
                    // box.
                    //
                    JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) event.getSource();

                    Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    if(selected.toString().equals("Sim"))
                        txtqtdpesodiv.setEditable(true);


                    else if(selected.toString().equals("Não"))
                        txtqtdpesodiv.setEditable(false);

                }
            });

        // Icone




        JLabel lblPesoDivergente = new JLabel("Peso Divergente?");
        lblPesoDivergente.setBounds(342, 140, 106, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblPesoDivergente);

        JLabel lblestr = new JLabel("Qtd Peso Divergente?");
        lblestr.setBounds(524, 140, 129, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblestr);


        txtqtdpesodiv = new JTextField();
        txtqtdpesodiv.setEditable(false);
        txtqtdpesodiv.setColumns(10);
        txtqtdpesodiv.setBounds(524, 163, 138, 25);
        contentPane.add(txtqtdpesodiv);

        JLabel lblOutrasObservaoes = new JLabel("Outras Observa\u00E7\u00F5es do Material");
        lblOutrasObservaoes.setBounds(10, 195, 213, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblOutrasObservaoes);

        JDateChooser txtdtreceb = new JDateChooser();
        txtdtreceb.setBounds(21, 377, 142, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtdtreceb);
        String data = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());


        JSeparator separator_2 = new JSeparator();
        separator_2.setBounds(0, 351, 288, 8);
        contentPane.add(separator_2);

        JLabel lblData = new JLabel("Data");
        lblData.setBounds(306, 340, 88, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblData);

        JSeparator separator_3 = new JSeparator();
        separator_3.setBounds(350, 351, 338, 8);
        contentPane.add(separator_3);

        JLabel lblDataRecebimentoDa = new JLabel("Data de Recebimento da Pe\u00E7a");
        lblDataRecebimentoDa.setBounds(10, 358, 184, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblDataRecebimentoDa);

        JDateChooser dateChooser_1 = new JDateChooser();
        dateChooser_1.setBounds(432, 377, 142, 20);
        contentPane.add(dateChooser_1);



        JLabel lblDataPrevistaPara = new JLabel("Data Prevista para Entrega");
        lblDataPrevistaPara.setBounds(421, 358, 184, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblDataPrevistaPara);

        JSeparator separator_4 = new JSeparator();
        separator_4.setBounds(0, 420, 288, 8);
        contentPane.add(separator_4);

        JLabel lblOutros = new JLabel("Outros");
        lblOutros.setBounds(302, 407, 76, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblOutros);

        JSeparator separator_5 = new JSeparator();
        separator_5.setBounds(350, 420, 338, 8);
        contentPane.add(separator_5);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setBounds(10, 453, 652, 106);
        contentPane.add(textPane);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Outras observa\u00E7\u00F5es");
        label.setBounds(10, 420, 153, 20);
        contentPane.add(label);

        JSeparator separator_6 = new JSeparator();
        separator_6.setBounds(0, 582, 34, 3);
        contentPane.add(separator_6);

        JLabel lblPesoBalana = new JLabel("Peso Balan\u00E7a");
        lblPesoBalana.setBounds(51, 571, 88, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblPesoBalana);

        JSeparator separator_7 = new JSeparator();
        separator_7.setBounds(140, 582, 34, 3);
        contentPane.add(separator_7);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(10, 597, 153, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnGravar = new JButton("Gravar");
        btnGravar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                salvar();
            }
        });
        btnGravar.setBounds(572, 594, 90, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnGravar);

        txtoutrasdiv1 = new JTextField();
        txtoutrasdiv1.setBounds(13, 216, 649, 123);
        contentPane.add(txtoutrasdiv1);
        txtoutrasdiv1.setColumns(10);







    }


     public void buscar_dados() {
         try {
     Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Matheus\\Documents\\Java Apps\\Tratermik\\banco de dados\\tratermik.db");
     Statement stat = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs;
     rs = stat.executeQuery("select count (*) from tratermik");
     ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
     int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();
     Vector columns = new Vector(columnCount);

    //store column names
     for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++)
       columns.add(md.getColumnName(i));

   Vector data = new Vector();
   Vector row;

     while (rs.next()) {

       row = new Vector(columnCount);
          for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++)
          {
              row.add(rs.getString(i));
          }
          data.add(row);

         //Calculo Número da Ordem de serviço

         String osn = rs.getString(1);
         int osns = Integer.parseInt(osn);
         int soma = 1;
         int oscal = osns+soma;
         String osv = Integer.toString(oscal);
         txtos.setText(osv);

            ResultSet rs1;
            rs1 = stat.executeQuery("select * From clientes order by nome");
            JComboBox txtcliente = new JComboBox();
            txtcliente.setEditable(true);
            txtcliente.setBounds(229, 49, 293, 23);
            txtcliente.addItem(" ");
            contentPane.add(txtcliente);
                     while (rs1.next()) {
            String name = rs1.getString("nome");

            txtcliente.addItem(name);

            //System.out.println(rs1.getString("nome"));
                     }
             //AutoCompletion.enable(txtcliente);







                     }


     rs.close();
     con.close();
 } catch (SQLException sqle) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), sqle + "\n"+"Por favor contate o desenvolvedor ou o administrador do sistema.","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

     sqle.printStackTrace();
 }




         catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), cnfe + "\n"+"Por favor contate o administrador do sistema.","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

     cnfe.printStackTrace();
 } }


     public void salvar() {
         try {
     Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Matheus\\Documents\\Java Apps\\Tratermik\\banco de dados\\tratermik.db");
     Statement stat = con.createStatement();
     String os = txtos.getText().toString();
     txtcliente.setSelectedItem("Não funcional");
     String cliente = (String) txtcliente.getSelectedItem();
     String resp = txtresp.getText().toString();
     String amassado = (String) txtamassado.getSelectedItem();
     String trincado = (String) txttrincado.getSelectedItem();
     String peso = (String) txtpesodiv.getSelectedItem();
     String pesodiv = (String) txtqtdpesodiv.getText().toString();
     String outrasdiv =  txtoutrasdiv1.getText().toString();
     String dtreceb = ((JTextField) this.txtdtreceb.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();


     if (pesodiv.equals("")) {
         pesodiv = "N/A";
     }
     if (outrasdiv.equals("")) {
         outrasdiv = "N/A";
     }

     try {

     stat.executeQuery("INSERT INTO Tratermik (_id, cliente, Responsavel_Relatorio, Material_Trincado,Mateiral_Amassado,Quantidade_Divergente,Peso_Divergente,Motivo_Divergencia,data_inicio,data_fim,foto,peso,outros)"
            + "values ('"+os+"','"+cliente+"','"+resp+"','"+trincado+"','"+amassado+"','"+peso+"','"+pesodiv+"','"+outrasdiv+"',"
                    + "'"+dtreceb+"','a','a','a','a')");
     } catch(Exception e) { }





     con.close();
 } catch (SQLException sqle) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), sqle + "\n"+"Por favor contate o desenvolvedor ou o administrador do sistema.","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

     sqle.printStackTrace();
 }




         catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), cnfe + "\n"+"Por favor contate o administrador do sistema.","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

     cnfe.printStackTrace();
 } }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1º - Problema com componente JDateChoose

Neste trecho dentro do seu construtor:

```
JDateChooser txtdtreceb = new JDateChooser();
txtdtreceb.setBounds(21, 377, 142, 20);
contentPane.add(txtdtreceb);
```

Você está declarando uma variável local de mesmo nome de uma variável declarada no inicio da sua classe(`JDateChooser txtdtreceb = new JDateChooser();`). A JVM vai considerar sempre a variável local dentro daquele método(no seu caso, no construtor), já que não há referencia explícita de propriedade de classe, através do `this`.

Remova a linha `JDateChooser txtdtreceb = new JDateChooser();` para resolver o problema.

> 2º - Problema com o componente JComboBox

O mesmo problema anterior, você está iniciando um `JComboBox` local de nome `txttrincado` dentro do construtor, nessa linha:

```
JComboBox txttrincado = new JComboBox();
txttrincado.setBounds(10, 163, 129, 25);
contentPane.add(txttrincado);
```

E está fazendo o mesmo para todas as outras propriedades que declarou no inicio classe, provavelmente surgirão muitos outros erros desse tipo.

---

## Explicação do problema

Quando você inicia uma classe declarando propriedadea, para fazer referencia a elas nos métodos desta classe, **é recomendável** que se use o `this`, a não ser que tenha certeza de que não vai setar o mesmo nome de qualquer uma das propriedades para outras variáveis de escopo local.

A vantagem de sempre referenciar variáveis que são propriedades de classe com o `this` é que faz com que a identificação destas fique mais fácil, pois ao ver o this, já saberemos que a referencia é a uma propriedade daquela classe.

Apenas um exemplo do erro que você está cometendo, só para ficar mais claro:

```
class A {

    private String myScope = "property";

    //...
    public A() {
        String myScope = "local variable";

        System.out.println(this.myScope);
        System.out.println(myScope);
    }
}
```

Repare que declarei `myScope` como propriedade da classe, mas acabei criando uma variável local de mesmo nome no construtor. A saída do console será:

> property
> local variable

---

Outra coisa que é importante alertar é quanto ao nome da classe. Há um [padrão a ser seguido](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), onde a primeira letra deve ser maiúscula, seguida de minúsculas, e em caso de nomes contendo palavras concatenadas, a inicial da palavra seguinte deve iniciar maiúscula também, procedida de letras minúsculas(Ex.: MinhaClasse).

Dê uma revisada no seu código, localize as variáveis locais de mesmo nome que as propriedades da classe, para evitar que outros elementos deem o mesmo erro.

Comment: Realizei as alterações conforme informado e funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.