# Aquisição de dados por parte da JTable

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

Estou a tentar que o `JButtonGuardar(panelInserir)` passe os dados introduzidos pelo utilizador(texto hora local) do `JPanelInserir` para o `JPanelEventos`(onde está a JTable)

De momento, não estou a obter sucesso, se tiverem alguma sugestão deixo a seguir o código de onde está ocorrendo o problema:

> erro: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   net.ruimendes.Tentativa$8.actionPerformed(Tentativa.java:417)

Código de onde está ocorrendo o erro:

```
JButton btnGuardar = new JButton("Guardar");
btnGuardar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            double hora = Double.parseDouble(textHoraInicio.getText());
            String texto = textTexto.getText();
            String local = textLocal.getText();
            Agendado agen = new Agendado(hora, texto, local);
            eventoAtual.adicionaAgendado(agen);
            textHoraInicio.setText(String.format("%.2f", eventoAtual.getHora()));
            textHoraInicio.setText("");
            textTexto.setText("");
            textLocal.setText("");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AgendadoNuloException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
});
```

O código completo está [neste link](http://pastebin.com/50cFyuCf)

Comment: Rui, por mais que adicionar o fonte completo as vezes seja um facilitador para localizar o problema, é importante também que você poste na propria pergunta, um [mcve], com um trecho mais localizado e menor do problema, fica ate mais facil as pessoas te ajudarem. Com códigos gigantes, muitos desaninam.

Comment: Dica, tente depurar seu código e localizar a fonte do erro(ou o mais proximo que conseguir identificar). Seu código tem mais de 200 linhas, imagina o trabalho que dá analisar um código assim.

Comment: ja meti a parte correspondente ao respectivo botão

Comment: Qual o erro que dá? Adicione na pergunta quais problemas está tendo, mensagens de erros que aparecem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre porque você declarou a variável `eventoAtual` no começo da classe, mas não a iniciou e nem atribui nenhum objeto a ela. Portanto, quando você a chama nesse action, a variável está `null`.

Sem contar que você está iniciando variável local de mesmo nome que seu atributo já citado(cheque o método `escolheNovoEvento`), talvez isso seja o motivo da variável nunca ser iniciada.

Já respondi sobre esse tipo de problema em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124423/28595), dê uma lida na explicação e revise seu código em busca desse tipo de problema.

Comment: desculpa mas não percebi o que tenho de fazer:(

Comment: @RuiMendes dá uma lida atenta ao link que coloquei na resposta, lá você terá uma explicação breve sobre o problema do teu código. Depois olhe o método que indiquei aqui. Se depois disso não entender, só falar aqui :)

Comment: foi o que ja fiz, estive a ler mas pelos vistos eu não estou ainda dentro dos termos tecnicos, depois fui ao escolheNovoEvento tentei alterar la umas coisas e continua a dar erro, e o programa nao mete esses dados que eu indico na pagina que quero....

Comment: @RuiMendes  ao faze `eventoAtual.adicionaAgendado(agen);` você está tentando adicionar uma agenda a um evento que você nem criou ainda. Onde no seu código você criou um `evenAtual` pra poder fazer essa chamada?

Comment: private Entradas eventoAtual;
no public void escolheNovoEvento(try catch finally);
so aqui acho... senão é isto não sei o que criar mais :(

Comment: Ai está o problema. Você não está chamando esse método em momento algum na sua classe. Logo, nenhum evento existe quando se clica no botao.

Comment: tem alguma sugestão? eu estou me a tentar guiar pelo codigo do meu professor mas neste ponto os projectos são diferentes

Comment: @RuiMendes nem tem como eu te responder, pois para isso,eu teria que estudar todo seu projeto e entender seu funcionamento. Isso seria dispendioso demais. :/ Infelizmente, o mais recomendado mesmo sej você perguntar ao seu professor, pelo fato dele já entender como seu projeto deveria funcionar e poder te dar uma resposta  de forma mais rápida e precisa.

Comment: tinha que entregar isto até ontem, e ele decidiu não responder aos emails a semana toda xD vou tentando ahah obrigado